# Difference between swtich-case sentece and ojbect contains functions in reducer funtion of Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I wrote a code based on this [tutorial](https://velog.io/@velopert/Redux-2-%EB%A6%AC%EC%95%A1%ED%8A%B8-%EC%97%86%EC%9D%B4-%EC%93%B0%EB%8A%94-%EB%A6%AC%EB%8D%95%EC%8A%A4-cijltabbd7). (It's wrote in Korean)

The goal of this tutorial is to make a counter and bulb with vanilla JS and Redux.

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvzqnvw17y) to the original codesandbox and `reducer` function

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_SWITCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        light: !state.light
      };
    case INCREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + action.diff
      };
    case DECREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter - 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I don't like the `switch-case` sentence so I changed it a bit. Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-js-redux-boilerplate-o7obo?file=/src/index.js)

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const tasks = {
    TOGGLE_SWITCH(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        light: !state.light,
      };
    },
    INCREMENT(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + action.diff,
      };
    },
    DECREMENT(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter - 1,
      };
    },
  };
  if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) tasks[action.type](state, action);
  else return state;
};
```

I think these functions are working in the same way, however second code return Type error while using `store.getState()`.

What is the difference between these two functions work?

Comment: I don't see how the second code is better, you have more code than before and it's somehow less readable. However, to answer you, you missed a `return` statement in `if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) return tasks[action.type](state, action);`

Comment: FWIW, I also dislike switch statements in reducers--but there's no reason to put those functions in the reducer itself; they can stand alone and referenced inside the reducer. Then the reducer is simply the lookup and execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` keyword:

```
    if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(action.type))
        return tasks[action.type](state, action);
    else
        return state;
```